# Echo multiple values with same column name in same table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables, a users table and a trade table.

Which look like:

[image]

The structure of my code right now is:

```
<?php 
$history = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM .......");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($history)) { 
echo("The sentence");
} ?>
```

Problem I'm facing is that I'm trying to echo the user_name which in one case has to be the receiver and other the person giving it.

Comment: Have you specified what you select from both table rather than use "*" selector and surround $fbid with single quote '$fbid' ?

Comment: I haven't because I think it wouldn't make sense since the 2 values I'm looking for are both users.user_name. And the '' around $fbid shouldn't make an impact, at least I've tested both.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not support questions with the [deprecated mysql_* extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php).

Comment: What's the structure of your `item_send` table? You only mentioned the `user` and `trade` table. And not sure but, is it alright not to use apostrophe (') on your `$fbid` variable inside the query? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I've deleted some crappy code @ZombieHunter and I've added a more clear picture of what the structure and goal is LoganWayne. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pro tip:  *Never* use `SELECT *` in software unless you know exactly why you are doing so. In your case it is harmful.

I'm assuming your query is really against the `user` and `trade` tables you mentioned in your question.

First, recast your query using 21st century SQL, as follows:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM trade AS t
  JOIN user AS s ON  s.user_id = t.user_id_sender
 WHERE s.facebook_id = $fbid
```

Second, use this to retrieve your user's names and the item id traded.

```
SELECT s.user_name AS sender,
       r.user_name AS receiver,
       t.trade_id AS item_id
  FROM trade AS t
  JOIN user AS s ON  s.user_id = t.user_id_sender
  JOIN user AS r ON  r.user_id = t.user_id_receiver
 WHERE s.facebook_id = $fbid
```

See how we `JOIN` the `user` table twice, with two different aliases `s` (for sender) and `r` (for receiver)?  That's the trick to fetching both names from IDs.

See how we employ the aliases `sender` and `receiver` to disambiguate the two `user_name` columns in the result set?

Now, when you use the php `fetch_array` function, you'll end up with these elements in the array.

```
$history['sender']
$history['receiver']
$history['item_id']
```

The array index strings correspond to the alias names you specified in your `SELECT` clause in your query.

So, one reason to avoid `SELECT *` is that you can get more than one column with the same name, and that means `fetch_array` will eliminate those duplicates and so it will lose useful information from your result set.

Comment: This is one of the better illustrations of aliases I've seen.  Every once in a while you bump into something that, `$understanding++;` Thanks!