# Echo different values in the same column in the same table

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to display the values from two different rows into two columns in a single row but I can't figure out how to retrieve the data.

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT wp_posts.*, wp_postmeta.*
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta
ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE wp_posts.post_type='product' AND wp_postmeta.meta_key='_sale_price'
OR wp_postmeta.meta_key='_stock'
ORDER BY wp_posts.ID
```

I display the data like this:

```
foreach($sth as $row)
{
?>
 <tr>
  <td><?php echo $row["ID"]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row["post_title"]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row["meta_value"]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row["meta_value"]; ?></td>
 </tr>
```

I'm getting this: [image]

While I'd like to get this: [image]

I'm not sure whether I should post this in the PHP, WP or SQL category.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (not images, or links to images.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152779/echo-multiple-values-with-same-column-name-in-same-table This should answer your question

Comment: Insufficient data. We need more table data to come out with an answer.

Comment: Try add `GROUP By wp_posts.ID` before `ORDER BY`

Comment: @Mr.Blue It doesn't resolve my problem, it just displays the price value in both "Prix HT" and "Stock" columns (same problem as before). I would like the stock value to be on the first row.

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

only replace your tables with this example

```html
$sql = "SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderID
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Orders
ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
ORDER BY Customers.CustomerName";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row["ID"]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["post_title"]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["meta_value"]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["meta_value"]; ?></td>
    </tr>
    ///your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that your fetch results are coupled, so I'd suggest that you print the fetch results in the rule below:

```
/* Print this when $row is in odd number */
 <tr>
  <td><?php echo $row["ID"]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row["post_title"]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row["meta_value"]; ?></td>

/* Print this when $row is in even number */
  <td><?php echo $row["meta_value"]; ?></td>
 </tr>
```

> In the end, according to the sample data you provide above, you will find that the 1st foreach it prints

"#" = '285'

"Nom" = 'Bouquet Opalin'

"Prix HT" = '25'

> 2nd foreach it prints:

"Stock" = '9'

> I did the example for you, click the link below.

[For your reference](http://stockeasymoney.com/ns2/test/SqlTest01.php)

[image: Table Data Same yours]

[image: Table Result]

```
/* added at 2018-04-26 */

<?php
    /*  include your dbconfig   */
    include_once('../sit/dbConfig.php');

    $dbConfig = new dbConfig();

    $query = array();
    $query[0] = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE 1;";

    $column = " ID, post_title, meta_value ";
    $table = " wp_posts ";

    $arr = array();
    $arr = $dbConfig->sqlSelect1($column, $table);

    echo "<pre>";
    echo "1) Print raw array data which get from DB" . "<br><br>";
    print_r( $arr );
    echo "</pre>";
    echo "<br><br>";
?>  


<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    echo "2) Print in table format" . "<br><br>";

    echo "<table border='1' width=device-width >";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>#</td>";
    echo "<td>Nom</td>";
    echo "<td>Prix HT</td>";
    echo "<td>Stock</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

/* Print this when $row is in even number */
    foreach ($arr as $row => $key) {
        if ($row % 2 == 0) {
            echo "<tr> <td>";
                    echo $key["ID"];
            echo "</td> <td>";
                    echo $key["post_title"];
            echo "</td> <td>";
                    echo $key["meta_value"];
            echo "</td>";
        }


/* Print this when $row is in odd number */
        if ($row % 2 == 1) {
            echo "<td>";
                    echo $key["meta_value"];
            echo "</td> <tr>";
        }
    }

    echo "</table>";
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: I tried doing that with 2 queries but I get the "Stock" column only for the first row. The other rows are just displaying the "Stock" value in the "#" column and "Nom", "Prix HT" and "Stock"  are blank.

Comment: Could you please paste your completed code here including PHP and HTML so as to help us both clarify the problem(s)? I assumed that your SQL query remains unchanged.

Comment: I re-tried using the query I provided in the original post with this: ``<?php foreach($sth as $row) { if($row %2 == 1) { ?> <tr> <td><?php echo $row["ID"]; ?></td> <td><?php echo $row["post_title"]; ?></td> <td><?php echo $row["meta_value"]; ?></td> <?php } } foreach($sth as $row) { if($row %2 == 0) { ?> <td><?php echo $row["meta_value"]; ?></td> </tr> <?php } } ?>`` I got the first three columns right but the "Stock" one remains blank.

Comment: Edited my answer, added example link, complete source code and picture of table structure and table data. Check it again and see if it could help inspire you in solving this kind of problems.

Comment: I can't figure out what "SqlSelect1" is but it's ok, I found a way to do what I wanted. I put the sql results in an array and I used a for loop that displays the meta_value for every element in the array. It works as long as there is a stock value for every element, which is the case. Anyway, thanks a lot for your time !